# Why not correctly displayed button?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is an example with a standard theme.

```css
.hotpink {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    
    border: 1px solid #999;
}

.pink {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;

    border: 1px solid #999;
}

.deeppink {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;

    border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 hotpink">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="left-side pink col-md-10"></div>
                <div class="right-side deeppink col-md-2">
                    <a href="" class="btn btn-default">отправить</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

duplicate on [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKLwmo) where the result is displayed on the entire width of the display.

And here is an example with the subject material-design.

```css
.hotpink {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    
    border: 1px solid #999;
}

.pink {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;

    border: 1px solid #999;
}

.deeppink {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;

    border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.5.9/css/bootstrap-material-design.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.5.9/css/ripples.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.5.9/js/material.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.5.9/js/ripples.js"></script>




<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 hotpink">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="left-side pink col-md-10"></div>
                <div class="right-side deeppink col-md-2">
                    <a href="" class="btn btn-default">отправить</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

duplicate on [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/reMGpJ).  Why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Well the stylesheets you added for ripples.css and bootstrap-material-design.css are causing unwanted behaviour for you.
Removing both of these stylesheets from the second sample( the one with issue ), you can see there will be no differnce between the samples you provided.

Layout and style issues can arise when you are refering to different stylesheets.

Comment: My question is - why do not the styles from the second example.If You know how to make a layout from the first example with the styles from the second, we could clearly show.